# Destination Host Unreachable after switching to static ip

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ip, ping

I recently switched to a static IP, and the first time I restarted my computer, I lost my internet connection. Help!

#### More details

(For the record, I'm on Debian 10.)

I can ping localhost, but not my router (router ip from `ip route | grep default`), and certainly not any external ip or dns addresses. Here's some output from pinging the router:

```
From **.***.***.*** icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I should probably throw in my `/etc/network/interfaces`, but I haven't been sure if I'm supposed to keep `lo` in once I'm using static, so I've tried both.

**`/etc/network/interfaces` number 1:**

```
auto lo enp3s0
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet static
    address **.***.***.***
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.100.1
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
```

**`/etc/network/interfaces` number 2:**

```
auto enp3s0

iface enp3s0 inet static
    address **.***.***.***
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.100.1
    dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
```

I'm not sure what else to add. Do I need to configure `/etc/hosts` differently? The current state is:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    user.group   user
```

(There's also some IPv6 stuff on the bottom that I figured isn't relevant.)

Please let me know what useful information I can add. Thanks!

### Additional Information:

Based on @Archemar 's comment:

Output of `ip a s` - (I'm copying this by hand, hope I don't have a typo):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_left forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether (some MAC-like address) brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet (my static IP)/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp3s0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 (IPv6 address)/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
        valid_lft 7180sec preffered_lft 3580sec
    inet6 (another IPv6 address) scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip r s`:

```
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp3s0 onlink
(static ip, but with 0 as the last number)/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src (static ip address)
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. lo is to be kept, no matter dhcp or static IP. There is no need to edit out IP in 192.168.1.X range, those are internal to  your domestic/home network and are unreachable from the wild internet.  please edit your post with result of both `ip a s` (ip address show) and `ip r s` (ip route show). do you have a **default** entry as result of letter command ?

Comment: @Archemar I'm adding the two `ip` commands you mentioned - I have to copy by hand, so it's taking some time. What do you mean by a default entry of letter command?

Comment: Does the top secret address start 192.168.1. ? If not then you need to fix the broadcast address. Is your setup a PC connected to a router connected to the outside? Did you get (buy?) a static ip address from your network provider? The gateway address is almost certainly wrong as well.

Comment: @icarus I did purchase the static ip from my provider. I'm not sure what the top secret address is, but my PC is connected to a router that's sitting right next to it.

Comment: good ! gateway is on 192.168.**100**.1 while your IP looks like 192.168.**1**.X. use either 100 or 1 for both.

Comment: your host is not connected **directly** on internet ? you have some kind of ADSL of fiber modem right ? that's the equipement holding you purchased address. your computer only have local NAT address (e;g. 192.168.1.X).

Comment: OK. Then the static address should be configured on the **router**, not the debian 10 machine. You can either have a static or dynamic address for the debian machine. Next vital question. The static address you got did is come with a "/30" at the end of it or a smaller number after the slash or no slash at all?

Comment: @icarus when the ISP told me the address, they did not include a slash and value at all. Is there a way I can check and verify?

Comment: @Archemar I take it this means I need to revert my `/etc/network/interfaces` to the default parameters?

Comment: My current best guess is that the ISP have configured their DHCP server to always serve you the same "static" address. I suggest you change your debian host back to how it was before you started, and then use one of the services such as "whatismyipaddress.com" or ask google "what is my ip address" from the debian box and see if it agrees with the static ip address you have bought.

Comment: Wow! I seem to have really outdone myself this time. I just assumed that I needed to configure the static ip on my local machine too. I'm trying to figure out what my defaults are, but it seems obvious that this is the right answer. Thank you both so much for your time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I see no reason to downvote, OP mistake home static IP (static IP for modem) and computer static IP. this is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poster appears to have a typical home network setup, with a single "static" ip address connected to the network. This is being used by a router which is doing NAT.

Edit: Unless you are given a static IP address by your ISP and it ends in a slash followed 30 or doesn't have a slash at all (e.g. 7.1.18.32/30 or 7.1.18.32) then you probably don't need to do anything at all. You only need do something if there is a slash an the number is **smaller** than 30 (e.g. 7.1.18.32/28), which is not going to be the case for the typical home user.

The poster can choose to configure the dhcp server in the router to always give a fixed address to his debian machine, and then (again on the router) arrange for particular ports to be forwarded to his debian machine (or any other machine he has). Some routers have a concept of DMZ (de-militarized zone) where **all** ports are forwarded to a designated machine, but this is not recommended for security.

The poster could also configure his debian box to have a fixed IP address compatible with the LAN side of the router. There is no real advantage in doing so and some disadvantages, for instance if he took his machine to a different location and wasn't using dhcp then there may be either no network connectivity or else there may be address clashes.

Comment: I'd love to give you the answer, but could you do me a favor and just add the following: "If you get a static IP from your ISP, there is **no need** to configure your personal computer to use a static IP"? I feel like that will give someone who falls down the same hole as me clear guidance. (The rest is amazing, don't get me wrong, but if I would've found a sentence like that, this never would have happened to me.)

Comment: The problem is that it may not be true. If your ISP had told you that the address was 7.1.18.32/28 (an address picked at random but belonging to the American DoD) then the answer would be very different. This was why I asked if the address ended in /30, a smaller number or no number at all. /30 is pretty much the smallest you can get. IPv4 addresses are 32 bit, and the /30 says that the address part of it is 30 bits. This leaves 2 bits (or 4 addresses) for you. One is used as the network address, one for your machine (router in this case), one for the ISP router and one for broadcast.

Comment: If it was say /29 then there are 8 addresses so you could have 5 machines (network, broadcast and ISP router are still needed from the 8 address). In that setup you would want to have a switch rather than a router to connect your 5 macines and they **would** need to be configured to match the static address provided (Well you could hope the ISP router would provide DHCP but that would not be a great setup).

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

According to your subnetmask your broadcast ip and gateway aren't in the same subnet, this would cause the default gateway not beeing reachable, depending on your private ip address. Have a look at how subnetmasks are working.